# Basic concept of ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $I$ be an ideal of commutative ring $R$ which is not $R$ ($I \neq R$).

Then there exist an element $r$ such that in $R$, but not in $I$.

However, $I$ is closed under multiplication, so $rI$ is in $I$.

Then $r*1_R$ is also in $I$, then $I$ contains $r$.

Where am I wrong? I think it is very basic concept, but I'm confused..

Ring should not be include $1$, but in my book, assumed to be included by default..

Can you give me some hint..? haha

Comment: $1_R \in I \iff I=R$.

Comment: Not all ideals contain the identity! (In fact, most don't!)

Comment: $rI$ is in $I$ but $r\times1_R$ is not

Comment: Oh! Thank you everyone.. not all ideals contain the identity..! Thank you! :)

Comment: Even more, the ideals that contains the identity element are not fun as those are equal to the full ring!

Comment: Then, if the ring doesn't have identity element, then multiplicative inverse can't defined? These ring is cannot be a division ring, right?

Answer (score 1):

$I$ is closed under multiplication with all of $R$, so for any $i\in I$, we have $ri\in I$ (in other words, $rI\subseteq I$).

However, $1_R\notin I$, so there is no reason to assume that $r1_R\in I$; the above statement doesn't cover this case. In fact, this calculation proves that $1_R\in I\iff I=R$.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the ideal and its elements.

Indeed if $I \subsetneq R$, it exists an element $r \in R$ with $r \notin I$. But then $rI$ is an ideal namely $rI = \{r i \mid i \in I\}$ not and element of $I$.

*Note: you may even be confusing $I$ with the identity element $I_R$ for the multiplication of $R$.*